# How to use <merge> tag programmatically in java class without using xml layout in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create this layout in android without using xml.

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:background="#ffeee9e2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.5"
        tools:context=".MyActivity" />

    <include layout="@layout/buttons" />

</merge>
```

But I did not find merge tag in android code. So, I used Relative Layout as main parent layout which is as follows:

```
 private RelativeLayout mainActivityLayout;

 mainActivityLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutMainParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = new SwipeFlingAdapterView(this);
    flingContainer.setId(Constants.generateViewId());
    flingContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffeee9e2"));
    //flingContainer.setRotation((float)15.5);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams flingContainerLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    mainActivityLayout.addView(flingContainer, flingContainerLayoutParams);
    setContentView(mainActivityLayout, relativeLayoutMainParams);
```

Implementing this works, but is there any better way of using merge in android code?

Also if I need to add another view in this mainActivityLayout, calling addView() and providing params works. 
Is adding reusable view using addView() in class is same as using  tag in xml?

Comment: "Is adding reusable view using addView() in class is same as using tag in xml?" - this question is unclear.

Comment: I mean to say that "I have created a view that is reusable, so If I have to use it in another screen then I can add it by calling addView(view, params) on another screen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<merge>` is not something you use programatically - it's not a `View`. It's a compile-time attribute that lets the tools know to - well - *merge* the given layouts into any other layout that includes them.

See the documentation for more: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge

Comment: Then, is the java code above is the correct way to implement?

Comment: Well, it depends on which type of layout the merge one was intended to be used in. If it was a RelativeLayout, then sure, that will work assuming that you also inflate and add the "layout_buttons" one that is `<include>`ed in the merge layout.

Comment: Thank you for your help.